# VBA: Set border for Powerpoint table

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I try to set a border to a existing powerpoint table. It runs through fine (and the row and column number is inserted in each cell as test data), but the border just does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

```
For i = 1 To myPresentation.Slides(w).Shapes(tableName).Table.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myPresentation.Slides(w).Shapes(tableName).Table.Columns.Count
        myPresentation.Slides(w).Shapes(tableName).Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "R:" & i & " C:" & j
         With myPresentation.Slides(w).Shapes(tableName).Table.Cell(i, j)
            .Borders(ppBorderTop).DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            .Borders(ppBorderBottom).DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            .Borders(ppBorderLeft).DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            .Borders(ppBorderRight).DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            .Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 110, 0)
            .Borders(ppBorderBottom).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 110, 0)
            .Borders(ppBorderLeft).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 110, 0)
            .Borders(ppBorderRight).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 110, 0)
            .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Weight = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderTop).Weight = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Weight = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderRight).Weight = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Visible = msoTrue
            .Borders(ppBorderTop).Visible = msoTrue
            .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Visible = msoTrue
            .Borders(ppBorderRight).Visible = msoTrue
        End With
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single slide presentation and add only two tables on it. Then run this code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        Set myTable = sh.Table
        myTable.Cell(1, 1).Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 110, 0)
    Next sh

End Sub
```

It should work.
From there try to build a bit further.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. I relized that the problem is, that I am using an Excel macro, because I use data from Excel to fill an existing powerpoint table.

Any idea how I can transfer your code to an Excel macro?

While this code works fine in Powerpoint:
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table 6").Table.Cell(1, 2).Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 110, 0)

Comment: @Daniel - you are welcome :) You may consider marking this answer as accepted - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Uh, i just edited my comment above, sorry.

Any idea how I can make the macro work in excel?

Comment: @Daniel - replace  `ppBorderTop` with `1`.